# What is the correct tag? "Wishlist"

Tags: xml, magento

I have a module that displays calculate shipping on the product page and it works perfectly.

When the url is wishlist / index / configure / id / id_product, this module returns:

Fatal error: Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object in mysite/app/design/frontend/default/agenciasoft-tendadostapetes/template/catalog/product/view.phtml on line 141

I checked your xml, and thus can find:

```
<controller_actions>
    <catalog_product_view />                                
</controller_actions>
```

Liked something goes like:

```
<controller_actions>
    <catalog_product_view />
    <wishlist_product_view />
    // or
    <wishlist_catalog_product_view />                               
</controller_actions>
```

Anyway I tried the correct tag and not found, tried different tags and nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a search for all files with magento

And I was testing the most probable, and I got the one that worked:

```
<controller_actions>
    <catalog_product_view />
    <wishlist_index_configure />                                
</controller_actions>
```

If someone has this problem, is the ecomdev module zip on the product page, the changed file config.xml